# postgresql-12 Archiving not responding properly

Tags: postgresql-12

A newbie here and asking for your help. I did the the archiving settings for WAL LEVEL = replica Archiving Mode = ON, mentioned the location for backup: /home/beekay/archive for online backup for archive_command.

not sure why I'm getting this error now (screenshot in thread). Please help!

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). How did you check that `archive_command` was executing properly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mustaccio thanks for help
reciprocated and did write the command in the .conf file as mentioned in the book "https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Hans-Jurgen-Schonig/dp/1783988983/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=postgresql+administration+essential&qid=1633294343&qsid=259-8910705-8650441&sr=8-1&sres=1783988983%2C0735711216%2CB088FQ71ZS%2CB08DD2X1HZ%2C3742309544%2C1838984852%2C3446453954%2C1783989009%2CB09CH9T49P%2CB001IU6JJC%2CB0059AM0DG%2CB07STGGQ18%2CB0747QCZSS%2CB0919WD2H7%2CB07J5QY5ZX%2CB00P01MCKU&srpt=ABIS_BOOK"
it works post the ownership of the directory.
thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you'd choose a directory where postgres is allowed to write.  In the one you show, only "beekay" and group are allowed to write.  Did you have a look at postgresql's logs?